# DynamoDB .NET SDK - UpdateItem skip null attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to implement something like `SaveBehavior.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` when updating an item using **.NET SDK** or I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

`SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` belong to DynamoDBMapper, which is the DynamoDB object modelling framework for Java. There are [two other](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HigherLevelInterfaces.html) DynamoDB object modelling frameworks, both of which are for .Net.

The equivalent library for .Net is the [.Net Object Persistence Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html), and the corresponding action is [save](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetDynamoDBContext.html#w2ab1c15c15c21c35c33), which does not appear to support the same save behaviour options as DynamoDBMapper.

Having used both, I know that the DynamoDBMapper (Java) functionality is much better than that of the Net Object Persistence Model.

As far as I am aware you will need to build your own function based on expression conditions.